# How do you apply formulas for a subset of data in a table in python?

Tags: python

I have 2 questions. I know that you can import excel files to Python, but when I try to it doesn't seem to work.

1. How do I import an excel file to python? The excel file is very big, roughly 500 mbs.
2. I would like to illustrate this but I can't seem to put in a data table in stacked overflow so please bear with me.

Let's say I have a table with 3 columns, column A, B, and C. These are farm data, column A is each of the 4 seasons for the past 5 years (so 20 words/titles total, spring2018, summer2018, fall2018, winter2018, spring2017, summer2017, fall2017, winter2017...etc). Column B and C are wheat and canola yields, respectively. A couple of questions here. How do I apply formulas (eg. sum) to only "spring" in column A?(so if you can imagine excel, with column A filtered for only "spring", then applying a sum function to the results). I would like to calculate the total yields for each of the four categories. The other question I have is, after I calculate sum, how do I rank them? I want to know which season collectively for the past 5 years is the best for wheat/canola, then the 2nd best, 3rd best..etc.

Bonus question: I would also like to take the sum of Column B and Column C and apply a 0.5 multiplier on it (to simulate results in a terrible year), how would I be able to do that?

Comment: take a look at pandas. It [would seem](https://www.dataquest.io/blog/excel-and-pandas/) pandas is usable with excel. SO requires questions with a limited scope. This question is asking quite a lot and doesnt show any concrete effort made before the fact (i.e. code). I'd suggest you break your requirements down into steps and see if you can find existing solutions on SO (or elsewhere), if not then a question might be the way to go.

Comment: Please ask one question per post. Also, it sounds like you don't know yet how to apply formulas to a small dataset coming from excel, so why don't you conquer that before worrying about the large one. It'll be easier to ask about here.

Comment: Thanks Paul, I'll take a look at pandas. Zev I'm aware of how to do the above in excel, just in python i can't seem to do.

Comment: See this tutorial: https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/python-excel-tutorial and then read a tutorial on pandas.